# Opening multiple files in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a list of filenames, possibly relative, possibly absolute. I want to open all of these files at once within an existing Emacs session. Is there a way to do this without having to open each file individually?

I could simply start another Emacs session passing it the list of files at the command-line; or if there was a glob pattern that matched only the files I wanted I could pass the glob to find-file. But suppose I simply have a list of the form `"../relative/a.txt b.txt /absolute/path/c.txt"`, is there some command I could use to open all of the files in the list?

Comment: Assuming you are on some kind of *nix, you could use `emacs \`cat filelist\``.

Comment: You can use [filesets](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Filesets.html#Filesets).

Comment: @Nick: Please consider making your comment into an answer - e.g. show how to define a fileset with some files and how to use `filesets-open` to visit the files in it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].  For now, your list looks like a single string rather than a list of strings, which makes it harder to write an appropriate answer.